# Is it possible for light to fall into a geo-synchronous orbit around a sufficiently massive planet?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, black-holes, photons, orbital-motion

Is it possible for (visible) light to fall into a geo-synchronous orbit around a sufficiently massive planet?

Can a planet or heavenly body be massive enough for it to happen?

What will that suspended light look like to an observer on that planet?

What role will the mass of light play?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere

Answer (score 0):

1. No, light cannot fall into Geo-synchronous orbit. Because light is emitted from on point and travels in **straight line** and terminates due to scattering or absorption. Considering the massive Celestial objects where it is seen that **light bends** are near the **black holes**.
2. It is impossible for any planet to be as massive as a black hole. Considering Black hole by itself, it is the one which gulps the light. There are no proofs of any planets such massive other than stars.
3. Assume if the light is being suspended, you cannot see light though u see the particles that are being illuminated by the light.
4. By the Energy, mass and velocity equations say mass of light at its speed is infinity theoretically, it stays same as long as the light is terminated.

Comment: Is it possible for light to appear to bend just enough that it neither falls into the celestial object nor escape it? Does your answer contradict the concept of a Photon Sphere as mentioned in @ACuriousMind's comment?